# Win32 32-bit process loads 64-bit kernel32.dll

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, 32bit-64bit

I am experiencing that 32-bit Win32 console applications are loading the 64-bit version of kernel32.dll on one specific machine which is running Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

Using [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) with a simple *HelloWorld* application it looks like this:

[image: Loading the 64-bit version of kernel32.dll]

It correctly loads the 32-bit kernel32 on other machines.

[image: Loading the 32-bit version of kernel32.dll]

The value of `PATH` seems to be if not identical so at least including the relevant paths in exactly the same order on the different machines.

According to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18(v=vs.140).aspx) from Microsoft, the search order for DLLs is:

1. The directory where the executable module for the current process is located.
2. The current directory.
3. The Windows system directory. The `GetSystemDirectory` function retrieves the path of this directory.
4. The Windows directory. The `GetWindowsDirectory` function retrieves the path of this directory.
5. The directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable.

I am guessing that on this specific machine `GetSystemDirectory` returns the path to `Windows/system32` instead of `Windows/SysWOW64` or that the mapping from `system32` to `SysWOW64` for 32-bit processes are not working properly but these are only qualified guesses.

Any idea what is causing this behaviour?

Comment: this is only mistake of Dependency Walker - nothing more. and 32bit app never load 64 bit version of kernel32.dll by static import. and paths/ GetSystemDirectory - not related here at all, because always exist `\KnownDlls32\kernel32.dll` section. it will be used

Comment: The last time Dependency Walker worked somewhat reliably was on Windows Vista. Be prepared to see confusing/misleading information out of Dependency Walker on any OS starting with Windows 7. A better way to diagnose DLL issues is to [enable loader snaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/show-loader-snaps).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dependency Walker is reporting the dependencies incorrectly. Its static analysis sometimes gets confused between 32 and 64 bit modules. Typically this is when you run a 64 bit version of Dependency Walker against a 32 bit target executable, or vice versa.

Rest assured that your 32 bit program is loading the 32 bit version of kernel32.

Comment: Embarrassing. You are right. :-) Will accept the answer as soon as I can.